# Extjs linked combos - let parent values have same child values

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have linked combos that work if the parent value has a unique identifier.
However, I have 4 options in the parent combo that should have the same value for the child combo. I've given these the same identifier in the store, yet the value in the combo doesn't change when I choose any of them.

Is there anyway to do this without duplicating all values?

*Stores*

```
var fields = [
              ["s","Name"],
              ["s","ID"],
              ["cc","City"],
              ["s","Cost"],
              ["r","Status"]
              ];

var operators =[
                [1, "s","begins with"],
                [2, "s","equals"],
                [3, "s","contains"],
                [4, "s","ends with"],
                [5, "cc", "equals"],
                [6, "r", "equals"]
                ];
```

*Combo*

```
xtype:'combo',                             
                        id: 'fieldSelecCmb1',                                                   
                        width: 125,                                     
                        displayField: 'field',
                        valueField: 'fid',                      
                        hideLabel: true,  
                        store: storeField ,
                        triggerAction: 'all',
                        mode: 'local',
                        value: "Choose a field",
                        listeners:{ 
                            select: { 
                                fn:function(combo, value){                                         
                                    var id = combo.id;
                                    var rowNo = id.charAt(id.length-1);
                                    var opCombo = Ext.getCmp("optionSelectCmb"+rowNo);
                                    opCombo.clearValue();
                                    opCombo.store.filter("fid", combo.getValue());                                 

                                }  
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filterBy function instead. Here's how:

```
    opCombo.store.filterBy( function(record, id) {
      if((record.data.id == 1 || record.data.id == 2) && (this.id == 1 || this.id == 2)) {
    // specify index that you want to exclude when getting say parent combo value 1 or 2
          return false; // excludes the record in the store
      } else {
          return true; // includes the record in the store.
      }
    } , combo );
```

Comment: all this has done is show every single value in the child combo instead of the select one. The issue I have is that several of the parent options have the same child options but the parent displays the first of these 3 (Name), no matter which has been chosen